# Multi Language Textbox in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textbox

I've been  trying to make a project that creates Flash Cards , and i wanted to make the user be able to input any text on either sides of the card , the problem I'm facing now is that since the textbox(from TextMeshPro or regular one) has certain font whenever I try to input another languages like Japanese or Arabic it simply shows as squares, I tried the suggestion to use the textmesh pro dynamic font feature but still with no luck.

my question is , is there any way to do what I'm asking for without using fallback assets for every single language?
are there any unity plugins that do the job?
Like I said the aim is to make a textbox that displays whatever language is put in it.
any tips would be appreciated

NOTE: the solution doesn't need to use  textmeshpro , it can  use standard text component or any other custom ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Since this is the first time I've worked with Fonts it appears that I didn't quite understand how fonts work and now I found the right way to approach the problem so I will give here the steps that I used to solve the multi-language issue:

1)you need a Font that supports as many languages as possible i found out that "Ariel Unicode" fits this need quite well with support to most common used languages support

2)you need  to create a TextMeshPro Dynamic font asset that uses the font chosen in step one. (I tried using TextMeshPro Dynamic font before but i was mistakenly under the impression that the dynamic feature "search" for a font that has a certain character rather than we need to supply the font and it searches within the font for a character, that was a bit of a stupid assumption at my part created from the fact that I didn't understand how fonts work) .[Here is a link how to use Dynamic SDF textmeshPro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slvRsAYS7zw)

I hope this helps someone with this process.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the font. You will need a font that supports all the characters.

Perhaps you could use different fonts for different languages.

`TextMeshPro` creates a texture from the fonts characters. This texture will get very large if you have a lot of characters (e.g. for chinese). Because of that, the standard `Text`-component should be easier to work with.
(But I don't exactly know how the dynamic font feature of `TextMeshPro` works.)

Comment: yes that is indeed my problem , and as i mentioned I'm looking for some way to fix that without having to create a font manually for every language, maybe that font asset(or other solution) exists somewhere that i'm not able to find, and i should add a note to my question , the solution doesn't need to use  textmeshpro , it can  use standard text component or any other custom ones.

Comment: There are more than 137k unicode characters, but fonts can only contain 64k characters. If you want to support all languages you will need some kind of fallback. For a font wich supports many languages you can look into [Noto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts).

Comment: Thanks for the info it appears that since this is the first time i work with fonts I didn't understand how they really work, your clarification really helped me figure out the best way to approach this,I was able to get a decent enough result in the end using Ariel Unicode font and TextMeshPro dynamic font feature, i will post this as an answer so people who struggles with this can find a decent walk through.